# My iPhone app is still in "test ads" status even after ready for sale

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, iad

I recently publish my iPhone app. I enabled iAds for my app in iTunes Connect in Manage applications. The appl is released and is "**Ready for sale**" but when I click "iAd network" and click View, I get this message

> Testing: This app is receiving test ads. This app's status is not yet Ready For Sale. You have configured ad preferences for this app.

Test ads show in simulator and I am not in the US (but I imaging I should be getting requests at least)

Help

Comment: How long has it been "Ready for sale"?  It can take a few hours to switch over.

Comment: As a note, you always will see test ads in the Simulator or in your development builds (to prevent developers from gaming the system).  To see real ads, you'll need to download your application from the App Store.

Comment: As an addendum, I think things have changed. You will see test ads if your device has a developer profile on it at all. Thus, either remove any development profiles, or use another (not set up for development) device to see the ads are there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually these things take time to propagate throughout the system. It may take until the next business day for Apple's servers to propagate the new information. If it takes longer than that, call Apple HQ and see what they say.

Comment: @Moshe that's what I thought at first, but the next day it still says test ads, but now I have 1000+ requests and no impressions

Comment: Call Apple HQ. That's what I would do. Ask for the App department. They've helped me in the past.

Comment: @zsniper- Cool, what did they say - and what did you say?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I said specifically the app and itunes app id, they replied saying they will try to fix the issue. It looks like they did!

Comment: Hey just sharing my latest experience here. I submitted through XCode4, and it was "Ready for Sale" on 19/June. Today, the iAd Network in iTC still says "receiving test ads". I just contacted Apple through their "Contact Us" form. Will reply back once it is fixed.

Comment: @Rocotilos - Great, please do!

Comment: Mine got fixed after 7 days. Here are the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442953/app-ready-for-sale-but-iad-receiving-test-ads/