# App Ready For Sale, but iAd "receiving test ads"!

Tags: iphone, iad

My free app was approved on 17 June. And TODAY (22nd June) in my iAd iTC page
it still says "Receiving test ads". Im a non US developer, so there is no way to check
what is showing in my app in the US. Im seeing requests as well. But 0 impression.
Revenue is lost definitely.

Btw some info about my app:
My iTC app's iAd setting is enabled.
My app is built and submitted using XCode4.
During testing, test ads appears normally both in device and sim.
My other ad (i use admob when iAd fails) is working fine and getting clicks.

I have also contacted iTC people through the Contact Us forms in iTC,
but I guess will only get a reply a bit late..

Does anyone experienced this? How to rectify this problem? Any way to have a speedy repair? It is such a shame that on launching where the exposure is the max, but yet unable to earn anything due to this stupid problem. *SIGH*

Comment: possible duplicate of [My iPhone app is still in "test ads" status even after ready for sale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485841/my-iphone-app-is-still-in-test-ads-status-even-after-ready-for-sale)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My app finally changes to "Receiving Live Ads" today. (25th June).
Here is what I did.
1. Report to iAdNetwork team about the problem 
a) Login to your iTC page and click Contact Us
b) Select "iAd Network" -> "General iAd Network Questions" -> "General iAd Network Inquiry" 
c) A form will come out and fill in those details (including your problematic app's ID).
d) Submit the form and wait for 1 week (this is the time I got mine fixed).

Hope anyone else having this problem will find this helpful. 
Cheers.