# My App Store app is showing "Test Ad" iAd's

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store, iad

My first App is in the App Store since one week now and it is still recieving Test iAds. In the iAd network it says "Live Ads". And i have the App Store app not the xcode version. In iAd Network it says 
eCPM 0.00% 
Requests 450
Impressions 19
CTR 0.00%
Revenue 0

I dont know what all that stuff means, and I have no idea why its not working!!
Link to App(its free):  http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/canada-taxes-tip-calculator/id449443981?l=de&ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Quick question seeing how I am also interested in this answer, did you use all of the delegate methods specified in the protocol or drag and drop via interface builder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My iPhone app is still in "test ads" status even after ready for sale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485841/my-iphone-app-is-still-in-test-ads-status-even-after-ready-for-sale)

Comment: @rich this is the method I used: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cM9DqJmj45g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked on other devices running it? If your phone is running an iOS beta you will only see test ads, even from app store apps.

Comment: you're right! I tried it ona non beta device and it was working fine! Thank's a lot!

Comment: @JoePasq When I came across this issue it was because I was running an iOS beta. I'm betting this is the issue he's having.

Answer (score 0):

As [I've answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485841/my-iphone-app-is-still-in-test-ads-status-even-after-ready-for-sale/4485854#4485854), these things take some time to propagate throughout the system. Try contacting Apple and see what they can do.

Comment: I also experienced this when my app first went live, within a day it was resolved I think.